# Is it possible to have a specific function override a general template function?

Tags: c++, templates

So, I'm making a serialization library where I want to save various data types to a stringstream, and then base64 encode a string of that stringstream, to then save it to a file.  It's all working well and good, except I'm having to make dozens and dozens of similar functions.  Perfect place to use templates, right?

Well, I'm not certain as to how to go about doing so, as while a good deal of the functions are quite similar

```
int save(stringstream&, const int);
int save(stringstream&, const unsigned int);
int save(stringstream&, const unsigned char);

int SaveLoad::Save(stringstream & saveStream, const unsigned int input)
{
   saveStream << input << Delimiter;
   return 1;
}
```

some of them, like

```
int save(stringstream&, const vector<int>);
```

require special handling like so:

```
int SaveLoad::Save(stringstream& saveStream, const vector<int> input)
{
  unsigned int length = input.size();
  Save(saveStream, length);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Save(saveStream, input[i]);
  }
  return 1;
 }
```

so that they store and load the data properly from the stringstream.  Never mind even classes, which will have even more customized save/load procedures.

Is there any way to go about doing what I want?  Or is there a way to make a template function only take in types of a specific kind?

Comment: _" Or is there a way to make a template function only take in types of a specific kind?"_ You can always specialize template functions and classes. Also you can check for specific type traits of the template parameters, lookup `std::enable_if`.

Comment: Search for template specialization and partial template specialization.

Comment: take in count that partial template specialization works for structs/classes but not for functions (only full specialization for functions)

Comment: Terminology: "override" has a specific meaning in C++; a derived class can **override** a virtual function defined in one of its bases. Since virtual functions can't be templates, the literal answer to the question in the title is "no", because there is nothing that can be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your programming question:

```
template<typename T>
int SaveLoad::Save(stringstream & saveStream, const T& input)
{
   saveStream << input << Delimiter;
   return 1;
}

template<typename T>
int SaveLoad::Save(stringstream& saveStream, const vector<T>& input)
{
  unsigned int length = input.size();
  Save(saveStream, length);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Save(saveStream, input[i]);
  }
  return 1;
 }
```

To answer the broader question about serialization: checkout [cereal serialization library](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal) for C++.